# What defines iterator name in for loop template tag?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In Django docs about templates, there is example of [for loop tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for), that iterates trought elements of `athlete_list`, but I can't find any information about what is `athlete_list` and where is from. I don't know what defines name of `athlete_list` iterator.

Example from docs:

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
    <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You pass `athlete_list` to the context, so for example `render(request, 'the-template.html', {'athlete_list': ['list', 'of', 'athletes']})`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks, but how about CBVs?

Comment: then you set the `context_object_name = 'athlete_list'`, or for an `Athlete` model it will do that automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't find any information about what is athlete_list and where is from.

This is a *context variable*. You can for example pass this with [**`render(…)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
def my_view(request):
    # …
    render(request, 'the-template.html', {'athlete_list': ['list', 'of', 'athletes']})
```

For a `ListView`, you can set the variable name that is associated with the `QuerySet` through the [**`context_object_name`** attribute [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.context_object_name). By default this is `modename_list`, so if the model is `Athlete`, then it is `athlete_list`:

```
class AthleteListView(ListView):
    model = OtherThanAthlete
    context_object_name = 'athlete_list'
```